# Using GLYPH Icons as check boxes (icon-check and icon-check-empty), how to get total checked rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Based on the fact that I'm using icon sets for the FIRST column in the row, and the default is (icon-check-empty) like this:

```
<i id="dataCbx{{id}}" style="text-align:center;" class="icon-check-empty center pointerCursor" 
title="Click here to check/uncheck the box. 
This will indicate you want to CLEAR this alert from the list. 
Click on another part of the row to expand collapse without affecting 
the checkbox" onclick="changeIcon(this.id); checkAlerts(this.id);">
</i>
```

So the user check a single ROW and I'm cool with that... but when / if the user selects multiple rows, randomly, how would I capture that?

So basically, I'm going to send the IDs through a web service using PUT and change the acknowledged flag to TRUE vice FALSE.

Here's the balance of the code that works when a user CHECKS a SINGLE box (COL 0). THIS CHECKBOX is NOT an INPUT field... but rather a GLYPH ICON.

```
function sortFilterClear(what) {

var listOfIDs = new Array();

if (what === "sort")
{
    //Sorting on attribute
    $('#alertTable > tr > td').tsort({attr: 'data-alert-level'});

} else {

    //First check to see if the "SELECT ALL" CBX is checked...

    if ($("#cbxMaster").hasClass("icon-check"))
    {

        bootbox.confirm("You are about to clear all alerts\n\n\
                        Are you sure this is what you want to do?\n\n\
                        Click OK to Clear or CANCEL to do nothing.", function(result) {
            //This is for the RESULT tab to pop out from the RIGHT OPTIONAL
            //Example.show("Confirm result: " + result);

            if(result)
            {
               //Send to command - CLEAR EVERYTHING!!!!!!!!!!!! 
                _clearCheckedRows(myAlertURL,'all');

            }

        });

    } else if (currID.length > 0){

        bootbox.confirm("You are about to clear a single alert with ID number: " + currID
                        + "<br>Are you sure this is what you want to do?<br>"
                        + "Click OK to Clear or CANCEL to do nothing.", function(result) {
            //This is for the RESULT tab to pop out from the RIGHT OPTIONAL
            //Example.show("Confirm result: " + result);

            //NOW check if the user has said CANCEL!!!!!!!!
            if(!result)
            {
                //IF SO, then CLEAR that SPECIFIC CHECKBOX and then STOP
                changeIcon(currID);
                //CLEAR CURRENT ID
                currID="";

            } else {


                //HERE's where we actual DUMP the a single row.
                _clearCheckedRows(myAlertURL,currID);

                  //HERE's where I'll check for MULTIPLE ROWS SELECTED
                  // SOME CODE GOES HERE    



            }

        });

    }
}

}
```

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Why don't you use a real checkbox and a label? You can always hide it and put the icon in the label. Than it is just plain old forms.

Comment: Would love to... but the project manager wants a GLYPH ICON NO CHECKBOXES...I'm ok with that since I have a function that I use to check/uncheck the glyph.

Comment: I did not say get rid of them! Reread what I said.

Comment: D'OH! Another Homer Simpson moment there... sorry. Yes, I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get list of your icon-check elements and that's your checkboxes:

```
var listOfIds = [];
$('.icon-check').each(function() {
    listOfIds[listOfIds.length] = $(this).id;
});
alert(listOfIds);
```

But it's a good practice to use normal checkboxes (with hide class) and set states via JavaScript

Comment: I'll try this... but we're delivering a DEMO today COB and I don't have time to change that... next week I can...

Comment: WE DID IT!!!!!! Thanks BaBL86. Was here at work til midnight last friday... Appreciate your help